# Clicking to the next page while selector exists on an AJAX page

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to access a page with casperjs and take a screenshot and then keep "clicking next" (and taking a screenshot of eachpage) while the selector "next" exists in the page.

My code is working on sites without ajax, but not in another website that uses ajax.
Basically, with the page that includes ajax, this is what happens:

1. access page 1 and take screenshot
2. click next to go to the next page
3. now we are on page 2, take another screenshot
4. click next again, to go to page 3...
5. we are back to page 1. (we should be on page 3)

Working example (site without ajax):

```
function printscreen() {
    this.capture('Step' + new Date().valueOf() + '.png'); // take screenshot
    var nextlink = 'input[name="ctl00$cphMain$Btn_GoNext"]'; // selector
    if (this.visible(nextlink)) {
        this.thenClick(nextlink);
        this.wait(5000);
        this.then(printscreen);
    } else {
        this.echo("END")
    } // click next and run again or end
}

var casper = require('casper').create({ logLevel: "debug", verbose: true });
casper.start('http://www.vertentehumana.pt/candidatos/ofertas-de-emprego.aspx').then(printscreen);
casper.run(function() { this.echo('finished'); this.exit(); });
```

Not working (only returns page 1 and 2 and then repeat):

```
function printscreen() {
    this.capture('Step' + new Date().valueOf() + '.png'); // take screenshot
    var nextlink = '#ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_dvwListItems_PGB a.dxp-button.dxp-bi:nth-of-type(1)'; // selector
    if (this.visible(nextlink)) {
        this.thenClick(nextlink);
        this.wait(5000);
        this.then(printscreen);
    } else {
        this.echo("END")
    } // click next and run again or end
}

var casper = require('casper').create({ logLevel: "debug", verbose: true });
casper.start('http://www.slot.pt/JobVacancies').then(printscreen);
casper.run(function() { this.echo('finished'); this.exit(); });
```

How can I solve this?
And how to limit to n (let's say 10) requests?

Comment: Links break or become otherwise unavailable. Please include the markup of the pager panel in the question itself, so that future readers understand the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the second page in your Browser of choice and open the developer tools (usually F12), you can enter `$$("yourSelector")` to test out selectors.

The problem is that your `nextlink` selects the *go back to page 1* button.

You could use

```
b.dxp-summary + a.dxp-button.dxp-bi
```

as the *next* selector.

As for the other question. Add a global counter variable and test it at the same place where you test for visibility. Word of cauton though, the visibility test isn't doing anything. The button is visible the whole time and even on the last page. You would need to check if the button doesn't have the `dxp-disabledButton` class.

Comment: I tested my selector with firebug, but on the first page only... Indeed when i go to the second page, my selector is wrong.